# ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 failed to convert m4p to mp3

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, itunes

I failed to convert DRM protected m4p files bought from iTunes years ago. Apparently, from what I read on the forum, this used to work.

ffprobe:

```
nput #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '01 Meds (Featuring Alison Mosshart).m4p':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A 
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: M4A mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2006-03-02T03:01:35.000000Z
    iTunNORM        :  00001A4A 00001C50 0000B942 0000CEBE 0002634C 00024ADC 00008000 00008000 0000CFA1 0000C535
    tool            : ??�
    title           : Meds (Featuring Alison Mosshart)
    artist          : Placebo
    album           : Meds
    genre           : Rock
    track           : 1/13
    disc            : 1/1
    date            : 2006-03-14T08:00:00Z
    account_id      : 
    copyright       : ℗ 2006 The copyright in this sound recording is owned by Virgin Records Ltd
    rating          : 0
    album_artist    : Placebo
    account_type    : 0
    media_type      : 1
    purchase_date   : 2012-06-22 17:21:52
  Duration: 00:02:55.47, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 137 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (drms / 0x736D7264), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2006-03-02T03:01:35.000000Z
      handler_name    : soun
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 600x600 [SAR 72:72 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
```

ffmpeg -i input.m4p output.mp3

Errors:

```
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] Reserved bit set.
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] TNS filter order 26 is greater than maximum 12.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] channel element 2.4 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] channel element 2.10 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] Reserved bit set.
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] Number of scalefactor bands in group (51) exceeds limit (49).
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] channel element 3.8 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] Inconsistent channel configuration.
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] get_buffer() failed
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] Number of bands (7) exceeds limit (5).
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] channel element 2.15 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] Inconsistent channel configuration.
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] get_buffer() failed
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] channel element 2.4 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] Prediction is not allowed in AAC-LC.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] Too large remapped id is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list. (ffmpeg-devel@ffmpeg.org)
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] Pulse tool not allowed in eight short sequence.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] SBR was found before the first channel element.
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] Reserved bit set.
[aac @ 0x5578fc676740] Prediction is not allowed in AAC-LC.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: Do you still have access to iTunes on any other platform? If you do you don't need to 'un-DRM' them, you can just get free replacements - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/149147/checking-itunes-collection-for-drm/149170#149170

Comment: I can use a Windows VM. But I have over 1800 m4p songs that I bought legally and some of the m4p can be downloaded from the cloud as m4a but for some songs, it just does not work. I know that they are software that you can buy or use for free but this is getting more and more difficult downloading a compatible version of iTunes that works with them.

Comment: I followed the steps on an old mac mini. It works but I still have 248 files that we not converted.